# How to interact with 2 dialog fragment lifecycle on Android?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment, android-debug

I'm very new to Android development. I have gone through many android tutorials and articles but I'm still a little bit confusing about my situation right now.

What I need to do: 
I have two dialog fragment, f1 and f2. There is an audio playing in background. when any dialog pops up, stop playing audio, when dialog dismiss, audio resumes.

What I have done:
I have implemented a listener interface with 2 methods: `onCreateDialog` and `onDismissDialog`. It worked for just one dialog (f1 or f2 pops up, and audio stops. Dialog dismisses, audio resumes)

What's not right:
A situation that: f1 pops up, press "yes", f1 will dismiss, f2 will pop up. The audio will stop (actually it's already stop because f1 poped up), then the audio will resume. So I checked log, it seems that f2 `onCreateDialog` was called before f1 `onDismissDialog`, that's why audio resumed when f2 poped up.

Does anybody have any idea what I could do about this situation? ANY help is appreciated!!

Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: So are you wanting the audio to stop all together again? I am confused as to the question.

Comment: I want the audio stops as long as there is a dialog pop up. F2 will pop up after F1 dismisses. @Ashton

Answer (score 1):

```
ArrayList <DialogFragment> dialogs = new ArrayList();

void resumeSound () {
    for (DialogFragment dialog: dialogs){
        //maybe isVisible won't work, try with isAdded() or add a custom     
        //flag like [boolean isVisible] inside the Dialog
        if (dialog.isVisible() {
           return;
        }
    }
    ....
    //Code to resume sound;
    ....
}
//Put following on each dialog fragment
onCreateDialog () {
    //Make sure dialog is added with a TAG or id, so you can find it later  
    dialogs.add(this);
}

onDismissDialog () {
    //you'll have to put following line inside an array iterator, 
    //check if TAG or id equals, and then remove 
    //(maybe also implement equals() for DialogFragment 
    dialogs.remove();
    resumeSound();
}
```

Comment: Well this is good point. But I'm not sure if I will be having more than 2 dialogs later, just not sure about the number of dialogs.